# Javascript Opacity calling function

Tags: javascript, opacity, fadeout

```
    var faderout = function(){
    if(foo.style.opacity>0){
    foo.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    var t = setTimeout(faderout,100);
    }
    else if(foo.style.opacity == 0){
    o = true;
    clearTimeout(t);
}
```

I can't get the opacity to exact 0, I just get it to 0.1000000004, any one know why i dont get it to 0?

Comment: That is how floating point numbers behave.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem

Comment: Why not lose the 'else if' and replace with 'else'. Also, I'd suggest just copying the jQuery source for the fadeOut() function. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Try foo.style.opacity = Math.max(foo.style.opacity - 0.1, 0)